# Data Replication in Oracle

Tags: replication, oracle-11g, materialized-view

I have a table on master site which only allow insert operation. I want to replicate the rows which are inserted recently so, need something which can track the last record replicated into the local site and perform the replication afterwards.

I have tried Oracle materialized view but still confuse that whether I use the Fast Refresh or Complete Refresh. I need all the newly inserted rows replicated in one transaction.

Are there any better approach to do that? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fast refresh would copy incremental changes over the network but requires that a materialized view log be created on the master site on the source table.  That adds some overhead to the inserts happening on the master table but would generally make the refresh more efficient.

A complete refresh would copy every row over the network every time the materialized view is refreshed.  That is likely to be less efficient from a refresh perspective but there will be no overhead to inserts on the source table and the master site does not need to create a materialized view log.

Oracle provides a host of data replication technologies-- materialized views are the oldest and probably the least efficient but are relatively trivial to set up.  Streams is a newer technology that has much lower overhead but is quite a bit more complex to set up.  Golden Gate is the preferred replication technology today but that has extra licensing costs.

Comment: Note that Streams is deprecated as of 12c (still works though AFAIK, prob more of a commercial move to get people to buy Golden Gate license...).